# Control open -f temporary file name

Tags: macos, mojave, catalina

When I use `echo 'hello world' | open -f` it creates a temporary file in `/tmp` folder with some arbitrary name.

Is there any way for me to set the name and the path I want for `open -f` temporary file?

Comment: `"ls | open -f" writes the output of the 'ls' command to a file in /tmp
     and opens the file in the default text editor (as determined by Launch-
     Services).`

Comment: @ankii How can I control the name and the path?

Comment: I meant that it might not be possible.. you can use `>` operator and do something like `echo 'hello world' > ~/Desktop/a.txt && open ~/Desktop/a.txt`

Comment: @ankii I know that I can pipe, I looking for a flag of a sort to do it for me, not using `>`

Answer (score 1):

What technically happens here is the following:

- `f` tells `open` to read input from standard input and open the results in the default text editor
- Because most text editors can't read the content to be edited from standard input, `open` creates a temporary file with the input it receives from standard input and then opens the default text editor on this file.
- According to `man open` there is no option to set a custom name for that file

As a workaround you can use

```
echo 'hello world' > /tmp/foo.txt && open /tmp/foo.txt
```

which technically does exactly the same thing.